# Does an isomorphism induce a diffeomorphism?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, self-learning

Consider two isomorphic real vector spaces, $V$ and $W$.
Suppose that $V$ gives a (local) chart for a manifold $M$, and that $W$ does the same for a manifold $N$.

Does that mean that $M$ and $N$ are (at least locally) diffeomorphic? And how to prove it?

Comment: I don't understand, I mean you need to at least choose a topology on your spaces and the isomorphim needs not even be a homeomorphism for the topologies. However you can always transport the Banach structure (usually for infinite dimensional manifold you specify a banach space structure on the vector spaces that play the role of charts) from one space to the other via the isomorphism

Comment: So @A.Rod are you saying it's pretty an obvious fact?

Comment: I'm saying that your question does not make a lot of sense as such. Either you equip $V$ and $W$ with a Banach structure, but there's no reason a priori for $V$ and $W$ to be homeomorphic via the linear isomophism between $V$ and $W$, let alone diffeomorphic.

Comment: If you don't specify particular Banach space structure on $V$ and $W$, then choosing a Banach structure on one gives you one on the other.

Comment: Of course in finite dimension every linear map is continuous so there is only one Banach structure up to linear thus topological (and thus automatically smooth) isomorphism.

Comment: Oh. I just re-read your question and I realize that I took the 2nd half of the 2nd sentence for a question but it is an assumption... sorry about that.
My previsous comments might seem irrelelevant. 
So to answer your actual question, the answer is "not necessarily" if $N$ is not connected (take the disjoint union of a circle and a sphere)

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort @A.Rod. The specific problem for which I was searching for an answer is "Problem 10" in this page: https://books.google.it/books?id=5OQlBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA278&dq=mathematical+methods+of+classical+mechanics+%22map+of+charts%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimxODGorjfAhVQzRoKHbrGBJIQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: I suppose that in such case (where the manifolds are compact and connected) the answer is "yes"